# Proper way to remove elements from synchronized lists

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, client-server

I have a client-server style design. What I have done is create a class called `RequestController` that controls and monitors all server requests made as a threaded object.

These request threads are tracked in a synchronized `Map` (created with `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Long, RequestThread>())`). Every half second each request thread is checked, if it is still alive it sends a progress message to its interested listener object (an attribute of the request thread) if it has completed or failed it notifies the interested listener and removes itself from the synchronized `Map` when its `run()` method completes.

The `RequestThread` object that I use to track each request is a protected inner class of the `RequestController` object that is monitoring all the requests.  So it has access to the map that contains it.

It is here that I am having problems. I get concurrent modification exceptions when the "dead thread" is removed from the map. All my access to the map is synchronized so I don't understand how I can get an exception.

Here is the control loop code:

```
this.reqTimer = new Timer("Request Timer", true);
TimerTask reqTask = new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(reqList)
        {
            for(RequestThread rt : reqList.values())
                rt.updateProgress();
        }
    }
};
this.reqTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(reqTask, 500L, 500L);
```

At the very end of the `RequestThread.run()` method there is call to the `RequestController` method to remove itself from the map like so:

```
   public void removeRequest(long id)
   {
       synchronized(this.reqList)
       {
           this.reqList.remove(id);
       }
   }
```

It appears that if a `RequestThread.run()` completes while the `TimerTask.run()` method is looping through the map of requests to invoke the `updateProgress()` method the remove is not blocked but is allowed to alter the map and cause my exception. How can two different threads get a lock on the same object at the same time?  Shouldn't the remove be blocked because it originates in a different thread until the update is complete?

Comment: `reqList` in the first snippet and `this.reqList` in the second are referring to the same object, right? Not enough of the code is shown to make that clear.

Comment: Tom Hawtin - ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Alex D - the first snippet the reqList is referenced from inside the anonymous inner class that extends TimerTask.  The second snippet is referenced as a member of the owning class RequestController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to turn my comments into an answer.

> How can two different threads get a lock on the same object at the same time?

They can't. The concurrent modification must be somewhere else.  I suspect that your `updateProgress()` is what is doing the removal from the list.  That may be where the concurrent modification exception is happening.

```
for (RequestThread rt : reqList.values()) {
    // you can't make any changes to reqList inside of the loop
    rt.updateProgress();
}
```

If you need to have `updateProgress()` remove the request from the list then you could either:

- Use an iterator and pass the iterator into `updateProgress()` so it can call `iterator.remove()`.
- Pass in a `List<RequestThread>` to `updateProgress()` and add the requests that are to be removed.  Then once you are outside of the for loop (but still in the synchronized block) you can remove the items in your remove list from `reqList`.

Comment: This was closest to what I actually did do. I simply stopped removing the thread from my list and just let the run() method finish.  I also switched to the Iterator as suggested and after each updateProgress() checked to see if the thread was still alive - if not then I used the Iterator's thread-safe remove() method.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to perform the removals **after** iterating across the list :-

```
  synchronized (reqList) {
    // Keep track of items to be removed.
    List<RequestThread> remove = new LinkedList<RequestThread>();
    for (RequestThread rt : reqList.values()) {
      rt.updateProgress(remove);
    }
    // Remove them.
    reqList.removeAll(remove);
  }
```

or you need to use an `Iterator` and use its `remove` method.